# how to create a layers of images on android app?

Tags: android

i want to put an image and over it a layer of some images
like a map and markers

```
Resources r = getResources();
        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.sketch);
        layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.marker1);
        layers[1].setBounds(0, 0, 3, 3);
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
        ImageView testimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        testimage.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ImageView's to a ViewGroup (AbsoluteLayout, RelativeLayout) and assign the ViewGroup a background image.

or

you can use a SurfaceView and implement the drawing of the images to parent by yourself.

Comment: doesn't matter, add a RelativeLayout, and then dynamicly add ImageView's to it.